# How do I module.exports a variable that is a result of a promise?

Tags: javascript, module, promise

I have code that looks something like this:

```
get_port().then(port => {
    start_server(port).then(socket => {
        var variable = {
            do_stuff_with_socket: function(){ ... }
        };

        module.exports.variable = variable; 
    });
});
```

Is this valid, or do I need to `await` the variable before passing it off to module exports?

Comment: you need to export a promise, and wait for it where you import